# How do I stop xserver but still have a terminal/display to run stuff?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, gdm, xserver

Hi i've looked at some other questions on stopping GDM/Lightdm to run stuff (Nvidia installs/patches) but my problem is using `service stop gdm` or `init 3`/`init 5` just leave my screen with no connection so I can't then run the command to install a nvidia patch. It's a recent ubuntu install of the latest version and fully updated

Comment: CTRL+ALT+F3 ................or F2 or F5 or F6.....  after you run the mentioned commands?

Comment: yup, no display. I've tried logging out of my computer and then swapping to tty2/3 after and before running the commands

Comment: sorry.. i didnt mean ssh... I meant are you remote  into it, like rdp or is it a virtual?

Comment: Try `systemctl isolate multi-user.target`. BTW, which Ubuntu version are you running exactly?

Comment: 20.04.1 LTS, I'm not remoting in as I have it in front of me

Comment: at boot, interrupt the grub menu, and try adding `nomodeset` to the end of "linux" line in your grub entry.... and boot... Once it is finished booting, CTRL+ALT+F3, then init 3 (i believe you'll be pulled back to tty1, then go back to tty3(CTRL+ALT+F3)